# How to create responsive static website for Azure using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: azure, web, static, responsive

The primary advantage of a static website deployed to Azure is the cheap cost (almost free), and the free SSL.

Reference this video by Scott Hanselman:
[A Static Website as cheaply as possible with Azure Storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_gDYlRBAZw)

Using the above video as a guide, I’ve already posted a little Hello World page (index.html) to Azure, and it works great, and comes with free SSL.  My little one-page website as an Azure blob, looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I need to make a small (but real) static website for Azure satisfying these 3 requirements:

1. Multiple pages
2. A simple way to navigate between pages, probably using
   tabs.
3. Responsive to desktop/tablet/mobile

My question is this:
Using Visual Studio 2017, what type of project do I create that will let me satisfy these three requirements in the easiest possible way?

Any thoughts will be appreciated.
To clarify: A static website uses no database, nor any server-side code.

Comment: you can use a web project and add html  pages to it.Maybe VS Code would be a better fit: https://code.makery.ch/library/html-css/part1/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i can imagine is to create a MVC project through Visual Studio.

**MVC** is a great pattern the ensure separation of logic into Models, Views and Controllers.

A tutorial for setting up a MVC environment can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started):

It satisfies your first 2 requirements:

You can easily create views that represents a web page. The documentation can be found in the first link.

Secondly implementing navigation is also quite easy an example of it can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038835/mvc-5-razor-active-navigation-tab):

For your last requirement i recommend building your views with the help of Bootstrap which is a open source toolkit for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It makes creating reactive websites easy and can easily be incorporated in your MVC project. 
A tutorial for implementing Bootstrap to a MVC project can be found [here](https://sensibledev.com/mvc-bootstrap-form-example/)

A great tutorial for build a responsive website with bootstrap can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-responsive-bootstrap-website/)

Comment: If you are more of a visual learner you can view this videoof someone creating a C# MVC website with bootstrap [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRqz_zUiJTw) PS. its quite long

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind that a static website in Azure Storage will not have the usual easy access to a server-side Model, nor a server-side Controller.  Or at least that is my understanding.